# Using the same button in multiple frames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm studying Java Swing, and I created some `JFrame` windows, in some of them, I created a button and they have the same solution (like search or save information), however, all the time I've had to create from the begining or use `ctrl+c` `ctrl+v`. Is there a way to create a `JButton` and use the same button in multiple frames?

And for `JTextfield`, there's a way to create only once and use for multiples frames?

There's an example using a unique button and showing a "Hello World"?

Comment: You can place any instance of buttons, textfields, etc. in multiple places.  But you have to consider context when doing so.  If  you have the same save or edit button in multiple locations, what is it your are saving or editing?  But the same instances will have the same event handler and you won't be able to easily determine which instance fired the event `(i.e. via getSource())`.

Comment: ok @WJS There's a simple example here in the forum or a youtube tutorial? For now, I just want to see how it works for future projects, I appreciate for your comment

Comment: There should rarely, if ever, be more than one `JFrame` in an app. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) for the many downsides of having multiple frames, and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) in particular, for alternatives. **As to the concept of using a particular 'button'** in multiple places, it seems you'd be best served by creating a common `Action` which can be used to create a button or a menu item, or added to a `JToolBar` or .. whatever, as needed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks for the answer, I saw the question about using multiple jFrames and i'm gonna make this solution, and with my searches and all the answers here, seems it's not a great idea to use multiple buttons for same action, however, for jTextfields or jFormattedfield, there's a way to formatted and use the same field in a jFrame and jDialog?

Answer (score 2):

Swing components can only be contained in one container (`JPanel`, etc.). However, most Swing components are backed by models, and those models can easily be shared between multiple component instance. In case of `JButton` there are actually two models: a `ButtonModel` and an `Action`. You can use add `ActionListener`s to the `ButtonModel` and that should work. However, I've never used that, since I prefer to use `Action` for buttons.

Comment: Ok, and about a jformattedfield? Same thing?

Comment: Yes, for text components, the model is called `Document`.